# Query to get result with different column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by

I have a sql table like below:

```
Id  LId     ModuleId    CategoryId  Type    Name
1   abc1    1           10          c       arun
2   abc1    1           20          c       a!!run
3   abc1    1           30          c       a$$r@n
4   abc2    2           10          s       ketan
5   abc2    2           20          s       k!!etan
6   abc3    3           30          c       roha###n
```

There is a `categoryId` column in my table. And there are 3 fixed categories `10`, `20` and `30`.

And I want result like:

The Group by of `LId` and `Type` column and records must contains all of the 3 category id's(`10`,`20` and `30`) in different rows.

So result should be:

```
Id  LId     ModuleId    CategoryId  Type    Name
1   abc1    1           10          c       arun
2   abc1    1           20          c       a!!run
3   abc1    1           30          c       a$$r@n
```

Comment: please copy the contents of those text files directly into the question as opposed to attaching images. people may want to copy the values.

Comment: All I see is that you are only getting the abc1 ID rows. A where clause is all you need.

Comment: Can be duplicate `CategoryId` for the same `LId`? Like: `CategoryId 10 10 20 30 30` for `LId abc1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If correctly understood you need to make groups by LId and Type, after It check If CategoryId have 3 values. In this case you can use `COUNT() OVER()` in following:

**QUERY**

```
select Id, LId, ModuleId, CategoryId, Type, Name  
from (
    select Id, LId, ModuleId, CategoryId, Type, Name 
           ,count(*) over (partition by LId, Type) cnt
    from #t
      ) t
where cnt = 3
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
create table #t
(
    Id INT, 
    LId NVARCHAR(60), 
    ModuleId INT, 
    CategoryId INT, 
    Type NVARCHAR(60), 
    Name NVARCHAR(60) 
)
insert into #t values
(1,'abc1',1,10,'c','arun'),
(2,'abc1',1,20,'c','a!!run'),
(3,'abc1',1,30,'c','a$$r@n'),
(4,'abc2',2,10,'s','ketan'),
(5,'abc2',2,20,'s','k!!etan'),
(6,'abc3',3,30,'c','roha###n')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Id  LId     ModuleId    CategoryId  Type    Name
1   abc1    1           10          c       arun
2   abc1    1           20          c       a!!run
3   abc1    1           30          c       a$$r@n
```

**UPDATE**

If there can be equal `CategoryId` for the same group, for example:

```
Id  LId     ModuleId    CategoryId  Type    Name
1   abc1    1           10          c       arun
2   abc1    1           20          c       a!!run
3   abc1    1           20          c       a$$r@n
4   abc2    2           30          s       ketan
5   abc2    2           30          s       k!!etan
6   abc3    3           30          c       roha###n
```

You can do It in following:

```
select Id, LId, ModuleId, CategoryId, Type, Name
from (
    select *, 
           count(*) over (partition by LId, Type) cnt2  
    from (
            select Id, LId, ModuleId, CategoryId, Type, Name 
                   , count(*) over (partition by LId, Type) cnt 
                   , count(*) over (partition by LId, Type,CategoryId) rnk     
            from #t
              ) t
    where cnt = 3 and rnk = 1
)x
where cnt2 = 3
```

With solution above will return groups only where all 3 `CategoryId` are different.

**DEMO**

You can test It at <kbd>[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/beee89/1)</kbd>

Comment: thanks........it helps alot :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this:

```
select * from (
    select Id, LId, ModuleId, CategoryId, Type, Name 
    , ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by CategoryId order by Id desc) numb
    from YourTableName
) temp
where numb = 1
```

This is what I understood from your question.